# Easiest way to send data from Ubuntu 14.04 to Mac via bluetooth?

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, mac, transfer

I got gnome-bluetooth in Ubuntu 14.04 to send some data via bluetooth. It functions perfectly fine with recent Android Smartphones (see pic 1) but I did not manage to send something to a (paired) Mac (see pic 2).

Does anybody made the same experience?

Pic 1: Cell phone **with** send button in right-hand corner
[image: Cell phone]

Pic 2: Mac **without** send button in right-hand corner
[image: Mac]

EDIT: Filled bug report over [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/1326939) in launchpad.

Comment: I found out that I cannot send data from Ubuntu to the Mac but vice versa. How can I make Ubuntu send data to Mac?

I figured out that when I type bluetooth-sendto into a terminal, I manage to send data to the Mac without any issue. Now, why is it not in the bluetooth menu in Gnome?

Answer (score 0):

Use Blueman, you should be able to pair and initiate file transfer from it. I don't remember installing it on my ubuntu, so it may be preinstalled in 14.04, but if it isn't, just look in the software center.

Good luck!